# Cruise Control Supported technology

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Can some body please let me know which all the programming langauages cruise control supports 
E,G :>.net java etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CruiseControl is written in Java but is used on a wide variety of projects. There are builders supplied for Ant, NAnt, Maven, Phing, Rake, and Xcode, and the catch-all exec builder that can be used with any command-line tool or script.

See: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I want to know which all the compilers it will support?

Comment: Ans also i want know which all the operating system does it support?

Answer (score 2):

**Supported Operating system**:

- CruiseControl.NET requires Windows with dotNET framework >2.0 or Linux with Mono framework >2.10
- CruiseControl is crossplatform, any windows / linux configuration with a JVM can run it (powered by java).

**Compiler supported**:

- No restriction on compiler. Any command-line compiler can be executed.
  Some compiler with have a better support for log result (MsBuild, gcc ...)